# LilyPond: formatting long footnotes

Tags: text, formatting, footnotes, lilypond

When writing a long footnote with LilyPond 2.17.25, the text is not breaking into several lines or respecting the margin limits. I would love to have it set to justified alignment as well, if that is possible.

Here is a tiny example:

```
\version "2.17.25"
{
  \footnote #'(-1 . 1)
    \markup{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eget ante venenatis mi consectetur ornare. Cras facilisis dictum venenatis. Donec.}
  a'4 b' c'' d''
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to simply add `\justify` or `\wordwrap` to the `\markup` command, as:

```
\version "2.17.25"
{
  \footnote #'(-1 . 1)
    \markup\justify{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eget ante venenatis mi consectetur ornare. Cras facilisis dictum venenatis. Donec.}
  a'4 b' c'' d''
}
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't work for `\wordwrap` if the string inside the `{}` block is surrounded with `"` marks

Comment: @UTF_or_Death Both `\justify` and `\wordwrap` need an argument without quotes. If you use quotes, it considers the argument as a single string and does not break it.